# Trying to get property 'title' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lsapp\resources\views\posts\show.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting above error while requesting to next page but I want posts title is as page  title as well

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('pageTitle', $post->title)

@section('content')
    <a href="{{ url('posts') }}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Go Back</a>
    <br> <br>
    <h1>{{ $post->title }}</h1>
    <div class="">
      <p>{!! $post->body !!}</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <small>Written on: {{ $post->created_at }}</small>
    <hr>
    <a href="/posts/edit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Edit</a>
@endsection
```

```
  public function show($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        return view('posts.show')->with('post', $post);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... can you provide the controller that returns this view so we can see how you are acquiring the data you are passing to it?

Comment: use like `{{$post['title']}}`

Comment: are you sent the $post variable in your controller to your view?

Comment: @lagbox yes I have edited and added the controller

Comment: @AmirMohsen Yes now I have Provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Post::find(...)` can return `null`. You will have to make sure that you are actually receiving a model instance, the record exists, before trying to use it. You can use something like `Post::findOrFail(...)` to allow this to fail when it doesn't find a record. This would allow you to continue in the code knowing `$post` will be a valid instance.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and giving your time

Answer (score 0):

Because the return type should be an array,
you can use this

```
public function show($id)
{
    $post[] = Post::find($id);
    return view('posts.show')->with('post', $post);
}
```